# Auto run of an app in background after reboot of device

Tags: codenameone

I am using a geofence for running app in the background. It doesn't work after the reboot of the device. How can I make it work even after reboot of the device in cn1? I think cn1 push notification uses RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission to achieve it. Do we have some inbuilt function to do so for other purposes as in my case?

Code:

```
Geofence gf = new Geofence("test", loc, 100, 100000);
LocationManager.getLocationManager().addGeoFencing(GeofenceListenerImpl.class, gf);



public class GeofenceListenerImpl implements GeofenceListener {
    @Override
    public void onExit(String id) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onEntered(String id) {
        if(Display.getInstance().isMinimized()) {
            Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
                Dialog.show("Welcome", "Thanks for arriving", "OK", null);
            });
        } else {
            LocalNotification ln = new LocalNotification();
            ln.setId("LnMessage");
            ln.setAlertTitle("Welcome");
            ln.setAlertBody("Thanks for arriving!");
            Display.getInstance().scheduleLocalNotification(ln, 10, LocalNotification.REPEAT_NONE);
        }
    }    
}
```

**Update:** *How to integrate following  in manifest through native interface in cn1?*

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:name=".YourActivityRunOnStartup">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a discussion about providing an option for features such as these to auto-reregister on boot but that would require additional permissions which might not be desired by all.

There is no RFE for that as far as I can tell as the last guy who asked for this just used native code within the Android library to invoke this but I don't think he shared his code.

Comment: ok I'll use native code. I've a question regarding geofence methods. Most of the time when app is in bg or removed as well, the onEntered() method is called. But onExit() is also called frequently. What is the purpose of onExit method?

Comment: It's the opposite of onEnter when you leave a fenced zone

Comment: I've work it out in native android for auto re-registering the app on boot, which has receiver in manifest. I'm not quite sure how to do that in cn1? (PS. Registering the receiver dynamically in the code doesnot work well) Have a look at update in above question.

Comment: Just stick the whole `<receiver ...>` block into an `android.xapplication` build hint